# Erro ao receber JSON de variavel

Tags: ajax, json

Dessa forma eu consigo recuperar os valores:

```
   var unidades: "101|102|103|104";

    function getValue(key, array) {
      for (var el in array) {
        if (array[el].hasOwnProperty(key)) {   
            return array[el][key];
        }
      }
    }

    var jsonTitles = [{"101":"20","102":"2","103":"98","104":10}];                  
    var quebra = unidades.split("|");

    for (var i = quebra.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var unidade = quebra[i];
        $("#lista").append("<p>" +getValue(unidade, jsonTitles)+"</p>");
    }
```

Dessa forma eu ***NÃO*** consigo recuperar os valores:

```
    var unidades: "101|102|103|104";

    function getValue(key, array) {
      for (var el in array) {
        if (array[el].hasOwnProperty(key)) {   
            return array[el][key];
        }
      }
    }

    var jsonTitles = latGas;                    
    var quebra = unidades.split("|");

    for (var i = quebra.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var unidade = quebra[i];
        $("#lista").append("<p>" +getValue(unidade, jsonTitles)+"</p>");
    }
```

A variavel latGas vem de uma consulta AJAX

Comment: Já tentou usar `parseJSON` no seu objeto? Pode ser que ele esteja sendo interpretado como string. Tente isso:  `var jsonTitles = jQuery.parseJSON(latGas)`

Comment: obrigado @RicardoPontual na mosca! Outra coisa... ali onde reparto aquela string teria como ordenar os valores em ordem decrescente ou crescente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondendo a sua pergunta, fazendo o parse você consegue ter um array de objetos:

```
var jsonTitles = jQuery.parseJSON(latGas);
```

Para ordenar, basta usar o método `sort` do objeto `array`:

```
// Ordem crescente
jsonTitles.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
// Ou ordem decrescente:
jsonTitles.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
```

Referência: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp